# Model doesn't change after sculpting

Tags: sculpting

Blender 2.91.2

I'm new to Blender and I can't work out how to solve this problem.

I've made a model and tried to shorten the neck in Edit mode, but then it created a hole, so i filled it using F. That made the place where was the hole look rough. Now when I try to smooth it, the modifications don't save and the rough place remains unchanged.

I've already tried making manifold with 3d-print Toolbox, but it but it doesn't change anything. The more vertices I remove, the rougher the place becomes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In Edit Mode. When I try to delete the rough place and use Grid fill, Blender crushes.

[image]

Comment: How big was the hole? If you filled it with the 'F' key there might be now a big N-gon that you can smooth out. In Edit mode, hit '3' for face selection mode and select the ugly spot, then you will see if there is one big face. Delete it, and fill the hole with Ctrl+F, Grid fill. This respects the edge loops. If this doesn't help then add a screenshot of the spot in edit mode.

Comment: @Blunder Edited the post!

The hole was small. I've deleted a face near to it before filling to make it bigger.

If i remove Multires modifier and add it again, the rough spot disappears. Maybe i should just sculpt it again and forget about this ugly place? :D

Comment: Oh, there is a Multires modifier. That's the reason. I remember that I had that issue a few times in the past when I changed my mesh. Suddenly my character model had a huge spike.

Answer (score 1):

It's the *Multires* modifier. It does not like changes on the underlying mesh and this can result in strange spikes or something like you have.

You can try to fix it with the *Multires Displacement Eraser* brush in *Sculpt* mode (requires Blender 2.9+). I am not sure if that helps but it's worth a try.

If it doesn't help, you can fix it with the 'cut-off' method:

- In *Edit* mode, select the bad faces of the low poly mesh and separate them with <kbd>P</kbd>, *Separate > Selection*
- Switch to *Object* mode, select the new object with the bad faces and remove the *Multires* modifier. The faces should now look clean and 'low-poly'.
- Select now both objects (the cut-off object and the original with the hole). Make sure you select the original last (=*active* object, *orange* selection color. This way it will keep the *Multires* modifier.).
- Join the objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). (If the *Multires* modifier disappeared then you selected them in the wrong order, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo ;-)
- In *Edit* mode, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, and merge the loose meshes with <kbd>M</kbd> *Merge > By Distance*

That's it. The mesh should look nice again, except for the "low-poly spot". You just must add the missing details (*Sculpt* mode) for the spot.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps a lot. The only thing I would like to say is that before joining the objects, you can add the Multires modifier after removing it to the separated object. I don't know why, but my Blender crashes without this step :(