# Spontaneous deformation of vertices when changing modes

Tags: mesh, sculpting, artifacts

I remove this spontanous vertex deformation in sculpt mode, but it keeps returning when I switch to other modes and then return back to sculpt mode.
This problem began spontaniously I didnt change anything.

[image]

Comment: That's a MultiRes modifier issue. It can happen when you edit the base mesh, then the higher MR levels get corrupted. Go to *Sculpt* mode, and try the *Multires Displacement Eraser* brush or re-create the bad vertices of the base mesh (*Edit* mode). Related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/242710/107598, and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214280/107598, and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/278413/107598

Comment: Thank you so much, god bless you