Unintended lines appeared during retopology work
I was working on a retopology of a character in Blender. After applying multires and shrinkwrap, I noticed that I had an unintended surface connecting my thumb and index finger. It is not visible in Edit mode, but only in Object mode. It seems trivial from afar, so I ignored it for now, but I would like to know why this problem occurs because I think it may affect future texture work or animation.




Looks like a glitch in the Multires modifier data. Have you tried "painting over" the area with the Multires Displacement Eraser brush? Related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/278332/107598, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214280/107598 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/242710/107598
